# Background Slider

Tags: wordpress, slider

I want a background slider behind my menu and logo, but I don't get it.

I see no pictures of the slider so I hope someone can help me with this problem

So I hope someone's can help me

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900italic,700|Prata|Qwigley' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/css/style.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>


  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <?php if(ci_setting('favicon')): ?>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="<?php ci_e_setting('favicon'); ?>" />
  <?php endif; ?>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

  <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php do_action('after_open_body_tag'); ?>
<div id="logo-nav">
                  <header class="cb-slideshow">
            <li><span>Image 01</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 02</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 03</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 04</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 05</span></li>
            <li><span>Image 06</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <header class="container">
<hgroup>
      <?php ci_e_logo('<h1 id="logo">', '</h1>'); ?>
    </hgroup>
    <!-- /hgroup -->
<nav id="navigation" class="sixteen group">
      <ul class="six columns left main-nav">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `<header class="cb-slideshow">` tag in `<ul class="cb-slideshow">` to make it relevant. Then, it's difficult to status about your script as it looks incomplete, we don't see the javascript firing the slider, ...

Comment: Hello Strategio,

Thanks for your help, but also when I change the Header to ul it also not working?

Comment: You can download the Header.php and CSS from WeTransfer because I can not drop all the code here. http://we.tl/WyVt9mFNhd

Comment: You have an exceding double quote on this line (here corrected) : `<script type="text/javascript" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>`. But this may ot be the only point... You should use a highlighting text editor such as [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) to find this kind of errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Strategio I have fix it. it was the double quote and   background-image: url(.../images/1.jpg) it have to be  background-image: url(images/1.jpg) :-)   But now I have 1 more question, How can now the slider over the background but want him just above the header and not the rest of the page?

Comment: I didn't understand your question.